# Cant solve "warning: conversion to 'long unsigned int' from 'int'"

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, unsigned

When I compile [mt19937ar.c](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/%7Em-mat/MT/MT2002/CODES/mt19937ar.c), a pretty standard random number generator, I keep getting issues with a bit of code that I need from it.

> In function 'init_genrand':
>
> warning: conversion to 'long unsigned int' from 'int' may change the sign of the result

```
/* Period parameters */  
#define N 624
#define M 397
#define MATRIX_A 0x9908b0dfUL   /* constant vector a */
#define UPPER_MASK 0x80000000UL /* most significant w-r bits */
#define LOWER_MASK 0x7fffffffUL /* least significant r bits */

static unsigned long mt[N]; /* the array for the state vector  */
static int mti=N+1; /* mti==N+1 means mt[N] is not initialized */

/* initializes mt[N] with a seed */
void init_genrand(unsigned long s)
{
    mt[0]= s & 0xffffffffUL;
    for (mti=1; mti<N; mti++) {
        mt[mti] = 
            (1812433253UL * (mt[mti-1] ^ (mt[mti-1] >> 30)) + mti); 
        /* See Knuth TAOCP Vol2. 3rd Ed. P.106 for multiplier. */
        /* In the previous versions, MSBs of the seed affect   */
        /* only MSBs of the array mt[].                        */
        /* 2002/01/09 modified by Makoto Matsumoto             */
        mt[mti] &= 0xffffffffUL;
        /* for >32 bit machines */
    }
}
```

Specifically, the error is with

```
mt[mti] = 
            (1812433253UL * (mt[mti-1] ^ (mt[mti-1] >> 30)) + mti);
```

I've tried casting it via

```
mt[mti] = (long unsigned int)
            (1812433253UL * (mt[mti-1] ^ (mt[mti-1] >> 30)) + mti);
```

which really doesn't make sense to do but I'm just attempting something. This code is from 1997- figured someone would have caught this by now and fixed it. How can I solve this? Or get my compiler to stop crying about it?

Comment: How about  `30UL`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh What is the `30UL` for?

Comment: to make an integer constant to be treated as `unsigned long` rather than default `int`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Ah, okay! In the case, I don't know what you mean by defining `N` to be `624UL` AND `30UL`. Both?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm sorry, I still don't know what you mean with `30UL`. What am I supposed to do with it? Assigned it to where? Thanks :/

Comment: I think `30UL` is not relevant, 6.5.7#3 said _The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand_

Comment: @8protons He meant `(mt[mti-1] >> 30`

Comment: @Danh Ah okay, yeah, still just getting conversion warnings -_-

Comment: @Danh it'e the integer promotion that creates the problem, not the result.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I think that isn't the problem, as OP said, he still get that warning

Comment: @8protons What is your compiler? and Version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change type of `mti` to `unsigned int` or `unsigned long int`

```
static unsigned int mti = N+1;
```

Because `mti` will be promoted to `unsigned long` in your given expression

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the problem is in the below part of code

```
 (1812433253UL * (mt[mti-1] ^ (mt[mti-1] >> 30)) + mti);
                                                   ^
```

The first part, `(1812433253UL * (mt[mti-1] ^ (mt[mti-1] >> 30))` will produce a result of type `unsigned long`, and the `mti` is of type `int`.

As per the semantics of Additive operators, chapter §6.5.6

> If both operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed on
>   them.

the RHS operand, `mti` gets promoted to `unsigned long` (from `int`) , according to the rule mentioned in §6.3.1.8/p1

> - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>     equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>     signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>     integer type.

which causes the warning.

Solution: You can make `mti` an `unsigned long`.

Comment: I did as instructed in your last sentence and still get the same compiler warning.

Comment: @8protons Ahh, I see, the logic is same, but the problem is with `mti` being `int`.